# CDAP ingestion from PubSub

Tags: google-cloud-platform, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-data-fusion, cdap

I'm trying to load data from PubSub messages to GCS files. 
Simple pipeline: PubSub source -> JSON Parser -> GCS sink.

Since PubSub only accept the data argument as utf-8, how can I decode it in CDAP?
Should I build a custom plugin implementing a decode function or is it better to pass my data as string using attributes in the PuSub message instead of 'data'?

Comment: The standard encoding for JSON is utf-8.  I may be entirely misunderstanding your question, but it seems as if you are thinking of JSON and utf-8 as two mutually-exclusive things... but *"PubSub only accept the data argument as utf-8,"* makes `data` perfectly suitable for a JSON payload.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for your time. The issue was about CDAP plugin. The publish phase on PubSub was perfectly fine. The problem was the retrieve of the message in plain text. I wasn't able to retrieve in plain text the PubSub message using the CDAP plugins, I was reading only bytes or the ASCII numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue using a Projector plugin instead of the JSON Parser between PubSub source and GCS sink. 
The Projector casts the byte message attribute of the PubSub source to a string (plain text).